# What's the difference between li #{variable} and li= variable in Jade?

Tags: template-engine, pug, templating

I was playing with [Jade Template Syntax](http://naltatis.github.com/jade-syntax-docs) and come into this (slightly modified from the documentation):

```
ul
  for book in books
    li= book
  else
    li sorry, no books!

{"books": ["First"]}
```

I can print "First" also with:

```
li #{book}
```

So, what's the difference between using `#{book}` and `li= book`?

**EDIT** downvoter: instead of downvoting without giving us an explanation, what about leaving a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is just a difference of output in html. But you are 100% right, there is a very small difference. `book` is the variable and `#{book}` is the text contained in the variable.

`#{book}` : will output the text contained in the variable book, which is **First** only.

`li= book` : will output the variable content into a `li` statement `<li>First</li>`

Therefore, `li= book` is identical to `li #{book}` and will output `<li>First</li>`

*You can even play with this a bit more:*

`h1= book` or `h1 #{book}`: will output `<h1>First</h1>`

`h2= book` or `h2 #{book}`: will output `<h2>First</h2>`